# Elegance in C# - copying and disposing objects

Tags: c#, oop, object, reference, dispose

Say you have three objects. First one extends UIElement and overloads members like MouseMove, MouseDown, etc.. Second and Third objects are of same type and can hold list of objects of First object type. They also subscribe to First object's events. How do I elegantly implement this problems?

1. How to move one instance of First object form Second object to Third object?
   Do all references and events have to be reconnected manually?
2. How to dispose Third object eventhough its list of First objects is not null (including every instance of First object as well in existing list)?

Thanks for help.

Comment: First question is about shallow/deep copy elegantly? Second question is about delete cascade or the same shallow/deep copy problem?

Comment: In its current form the question is way too broad. At the very least you need to show some example code of your classes, how they relate and how they are used.